# Is there an Android repository like Cocoa Controls?

Tags: android, ios

I'm looking for a repository for Android sample apps like http://www.cocoacontrols.com/ fo iOS, is there one similar?

Comment: sdk does have quite a lot of samples, especially apidemos project itself has many examples

Comment: [android custom views](http://androidcustomviews.com/)

Comment: I would recommend giving a try to Android Arsenal's competitor, too - https://android.libhunt.com . It's much simpler and many people would say more useful. I hope this was helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One good repository is Android Arsenal http://www.android-arsenal.com

Comment: The page is dead. It's http://android-arsenal.com/ now!

Comment: Yes, Android Arsenal rocks. My development time has been reduced after I started using Android Studio and Android Arsenal. Use both the tools wisely.

Answer (score 5):

There are also a ton of open source Android apps available and [F-Droid](http://f-droid.org) is probably the largest repository of these. If you do end up using code from any of them, be careful about the license the software is made available under; if it's GPL licensed, your code will need to be GPL licensed (and made available) too.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great repository for full apps, I was also looking for something more like single task.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't think there is one. There are lots of widget libraries on github and Google code, but there doesn't seem to be a good central source giving an overview of them all. That sounds like a very useful project!

Answer (score 1):

There is an app [DevAppsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect&hl=en), which I highly recommend. It has a large collection of libraries that you can even download and try out right from the app itself. Pretty convenient if you ask me.

There is this newsletter which covers these stuffs regularly, [Android Weekly](http://androidweekly.net/)

And then there websites which lists collection of libraries/components etc. Like [Appance](http://appance.com/category/android/), [Android-Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com) etc.

Comment: [Libraries for developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en) is also very good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the repositories from github. Here is the link

https://github.com/search?q=android&ref=commandbar

Answer (score 0):

Just Found another [website](http://www.appance.com/) Hope it helps ...